# How (if at all) is the standard library's API changed to use new language features?

Tags: rust

Rust is very actively developed and the language itself is extended regularly through the RFC process. Some of these changes, such as the [Generic Associated Types RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1598-generic_associated_types.md), have a strong impact on API-design, because new, better APIs suddenly become possible, where they weren't before.

As example, consider the mentioned GATs RFC: with this feature, we could have collection traits and could write a better version of some traits, e.g. `Deref`. Or take [the `impl Trait` RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1522-conservative-impl-trait.md): with that, it would be desirable to change the `Iterator` trait such that methods like `map()` would return `impl Iterator` instead of `Map`.

This is a conflict: we could improve `std`, but not in a backwards-compatible manner. I heard something about "Rust Epochs" ([discussed here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2052)) and I think they would allow for backwards-incompatible changes.

My question is: **Are there already plans on how to change the standard library's API in order to use new language features? Is a new design considered for the Rust 2019 Epoch?**

Comment: Regarding returning `impl Iterator`... is storing `impl Iterator` in a structure possible? If it is not, it would not be an improvement.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about language and API design. I think it would be better suited to the [Rust internals forum](https://internals.rust-lang.org/). I'd like to see an answer too, by the way... :)

Comment: @PaoloFalabella I just [asked in the internals forum](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/evolving-the-standard-library-through-what/5874). However, I disagree with the close votes. While in the internals forum my question is more of a discussion-nature, my question here on SO just asks about the current state of things; about facts. I didn't want to discuss here. I just wanted an answer like "yeah there are already ideas how to break `std`, see here" or "no, no one thought about it yet". Maybe the result of the internals discussion can serve as a basis for an answer here on SO.

Comment: New traits can be added to existing types without breaking backwards compatibility so I don't see why `std` would need to be changed to have collection traits. Additionally, I'm not seeing why returning `impl Iterator` is an improvement over `Map`. Sure, it seems conceptually cleaner, but I don't see a practical benefit. 

As others have mentioned, this seems like a better fit for the internals form than SO.

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt having read through [stackoverflow's help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), some threads on meta and ["Good subjective, Bad Subjective"](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) I'm not so sure any more that your question is off topic. I still fear it might be devolve into opinion-based discussion, but what if a plan does exist or someone can point out to one of the RFCs for a relevant discussion on this? In doubt, I apologize with you and vote to reopen.

Comment: @PaoloFalabella Thanks for doing a lot of research on SO-policy for this question! But don't worry; let's see how the discussion on the internals forum evolves. If anything specific comes out of that discussion, we can still reopen this ;-)